# MAAS server won't recongnize nodes

Tags: networking, juju, maas, vmware-workstation

I'm a newbie on researching and deploy MAAS Server with Juju and Openstack.

I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on VMWare Workstation with 2 NIC: 1 of them is external network with Bridge Mode with IP 192.168.1.110/24, another one is internal network with host-only mode with IP 10.1.1.100/24, then i installed maas and all things run fine. After that, i go to MAAS Web UI to configure image, subnet, bla bla. But i notice that 2 of my farbic with space of undefined, and i create another virtual machine as a node, with 1 NIC in host-only mode, node booted up and install somethings look like OS then auto shutdown, i powered up but the MAAS Server still not recognize any node.

Is there anyway to fix this??